# How to cut a substring from one column in dataframe and concat with string in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

So, the table that I have is as follows and the 'final' column is what i am trying to get:

```
col1   col2  final
56in   5      5in
78c>t  10    10c>t
```

Now, the col1 can have any types of values. I want to extract according to this regex condition - r'[a-z,A-Z,">"]. Can I do this using numpy.where() and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['final'] = df['col2'].astype(str) + df['col1'].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z>]+)', expand=False)
print (df)
    col1  col2  final
0   56in     5    5in
1  78c>t    10  10c>t
```

If need all values without numbers:

```
df['final'] = df['col2'].astype(str) + df['col1'].str.extract(r'(\D+)', expand=False)
print (df)
    col1  col2  final
0   56in     5    5in
1  78c>t    10  10c>t
```

Comment: This is not working. It is only taking one letter and not the rest.

Comment: @SayantanGhosh - it seems you forget for `+` in the end `r'([a-zA-Z>]+)'`

Comment: I am using the '+' also. The case I have has a full stop in the string, is that the reason only the letter before the full stop is appearing?

Comment: @SayantanGhosh - exactly, then need `r'([a-zA-Z\.>]+)'`

Answer (score 0):

Using [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), try this code:

```
df['final'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row.col2) + re.search(r'([a-zA-Z\.>]+)', row.col1).group(), axis=1)
```

and gives:

```
col1   col2  final
56in   5      5in
78c>t  10    10c>t
```